# need to speed up my database or query somehow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a left join statement on 2 tables: tbl1 has about 1 million records and tbl2 has about 20 million. The query takes about 9 seconds to execute. I have indexes on both but something doesn't seem right given how long queries take. Here is my select statement:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM (SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.name, tbl2.addr FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.id = tbl1.id WHERE tbl1.name LIKE 'G%' AND tble2.addr IS NOT NULL) as tempTable GROUP BY id LIMIT 10;

+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+--------------+---------+----------------| 
id|select_type| table     |type  |poss_keys|key |key_len|ref         | rows | Extra 
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+--------------+---------+----------------
1 | PRIMARY   | <derived2>|system| NULL    |NULL| NULL  |NULL        |    0 | const row not found |
2 | DERIVED   | tbl1      |range |id,name  |name| 903   |NULL        |    1 | Using where         |
2 | DERIVED   | tbl2      |ref   |id,addr  |id  | 4     |tbl2.tbl1.id|   25 | Using where         |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+--------------+---------+----------------
```

UPDATE:
If I take out the join statement & just select records from tbl1 or from tbl2 individually the select statements are fast (well under 1 second) but when I try to join them then it slows it down onsiderably...am I joining them correctly or do I need some kind of special index for joins?

Comment: 1. Why do you need nested query? 2. Why do you use `LEFT JOIN`? 3. Where are the tables structures?

Comment: The Left Join is used to join my 2 tables. I guess I don't need the temp table but when I modify the statement the query still takes a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simplify it a bit... I don't think you need a temp table or a group...

```
  SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.name, tbl2.addr 
FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.id = tbl1.id 
WHERE tbl1.name LIKE 'G%' AND tble2.addr IS NOT NULL
```

Also...if the index doesn't seem to be working you could add "tble2.id like 'G%'"

Comment: He doesn't need `LEFT JOIN` + `tble2.addr IS NOT NULL` either.

Comment: could you explain why he doesn't need `LEFT JOIN` and `tble2.addr IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: thx but the statement doesn't seem to be the root of the problem, as changing it to your suggestion results in similar speed

Comment: Are tbl2.id and tbl1.id exactly the same type?

Comment: Are the indexes on both just "id" or "id" and another column?

Comment: Can you try just "SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.name, tbl2.addr 
FROM tbl1, tbl2  
WHERE ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id 
and tbl1.name LIKE 'G%'  "  --- I assume there's an index on tbl1 for just "name".

Comment: yes, there is an index on name. I get the same slow performance w/ your suggestion

Comment: I suspect that the problem has to do with the optimizer getting confused when it pulls from the 20 million row table...Could you try "SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.name, tbl2.addr 
FROM tbl2 USE INDEX (theTBL2IndexForIdName), tbl1  
WHERE ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id 
and tbl1.name LIKE 'G%' "?  This might convince the Database to use the index for the bigger table, speeding up the process.

Comment: that seems to be taking much longer...queries taking about 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try many other methods

Try using

```
mysql_unbuffered_query
```

on php side that will make it faster i think as you have specified limit as 10 no more taking count will be needed

Then as result contains only 10 results

```
SQL_SMALL_RESULT
```

If you use the SQL_SMALL_RESULT option, MySQL uses an in-memory temporary table. so making small result query's faster

Comment: thx. I am using php but not quite sure how to use an unbuffered query w/ my statement, which is in the form of "mysqli_stmt_execute($q)"...As for SQL_SMALL_RESULT, I've read that it isn't necessary in version 3.23 or later

Comment: mysql_unbuffered_query($query); like mysql_query($query)